# Get CPU usage from application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cpu, cpu-usage, mach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Get CPU usage from application on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application)

I am trying monitoring the CPU usage in iOS 4.x from my application. I have found host_processor_info, but it is an undocumented API so I can`t use it. Exists another function I can use for this purpose?